# Can a limit exist at $x\to a$ but not equal to $f(a)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

In the calculus course I'm taking, the conditions for a continuous function are said to be when

a.) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists 
and 
b.) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ = $f(a)$

And it seems a little redundant, since if a limit exists at $x\to a$, wouldn't it always equal to $f(a)$? Are there situations where that is not the case?

I apologize if this was a bad question/ formatted bad, I'm pretty new to math and this site in general.

Comment: We use limits to study the behaviour of he function "near" the point of interest but excluding it (i.e. [deleted neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Deleted_neighbourhood))

Comment: The definition of the limit involves $$\color{red}{0 < } ~|x - a| < \delta,$$ rather than $$|x - a| < \delta.$$

Comment: @user2661923 This seems in direct contradiction with most definitions of limits I've seen in calculus courses. It's a matter of convention of course, but the convention I've most often seen is that the definition involves $|x-a| < \delta$, not $0 < |x-a| < \delta$; with this convention, you can still exclude point $a$, but you need to be explicit: $$\lim_{\substack{x \to a \\ x \neq a}} f(x)$$ Which convention is "better" is a discussion for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com rather than for math.stackexchange, but the only answer for OP's question is "what definition were you given?"

Comment: @Stef $~|x-a| = 0 \iff x=a.~$  If you don't (somehow) prevent $~x=a,~$ then you blur the distinction between the definition of a limit, and the definition of a function being continuous at a specific point.  The limit of a function as $~x \to a~$ can exist, without this limit equaling $~f(a)~$ (i.e. without the function being continuous at $~x=a~$).

Comment: @user2661923 For the first half of your comment: I don't blur anything. In fact, I make things more explicit. If I need to exclude $a$, then I can exclude $a$ explicitly. Which many math teachers will argue is better for the students.

Comment: For the second half of your comment: Well, that's just a matter of convention, nothing more. With the other definition (where $a$ is not excluded by default) then yes, if $a$ is in the domain of $f$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists iff $f$ is continuous at $a$. If you want to exclude $a$ for some reason then you can do it explicitly: $\lim_{x \to a, x \neq a} f(x)$ ; or if you want the limit from the right $\lim_{x \to a, x > a} f(x)$:  or if you want the limit from the left $\lim_{x \to a, x < a} f(x)$

Comment: And of course if $a$ is not in the domain of $f$, $f$ can still have a limit at $a$, regardless of the convention.

Answer (score 6):

No.

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      2, x=0\\
      x, x \ne0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

$f(0)=2$, but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a function with a hole in it, for example:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the function may not even be defined at $a$. One example is
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x + 4 & \text{if $x \neq 0$}. 
\end{cases} 
$$
Then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 4$, but $f(0)$ doesn't exist. I could also define $f(0)$ to be anything, say, $5$. Then the limit exists and is equal to $4$, but differs from $f(0)$. In either of these cases, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, this was a silly typo. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2):

This confusion often occurs because most, if not all, of the functions people are acquainted with in elementary calculus *are* continuous. In other words, they *do* have the property that if $f$ is defined at $a$, then $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(a)$. But not every function is like this. Consider, for example, the sign function or signum function, written as $\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}\sgn$:
$$
\sgn(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x>0$} \, ,\\
0 & \text{if $x=0$} \, ,\\
-1 & \text{if $x<0$} \, .
\end{cases}
$$
It's called the sign function because it tells us whether a real number is positive, negative, or zero. Note that $\sgn$ is defined at $0$, but not continuous at $0$. It is continuous at all other points.